# How to update DOM when changes occurs within an object rendered by v-for?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

I am using `v-for` to render a list based on an array of objects.

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="category, i in categories"
  :class="{active: category.active}"
  @click="changeCategory(i)">
    <a>{{ category.service_type_name }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When you click the list item `changeCategory(index)` runs:

```js
changeCategory(index) {
    this.categories.forEach((c, i) => {
        c.active = (i != index)? false : true
    })
}
```

So the clicked-on list items `active` attribute gets set to `true` and all others set to `false`, and the list item gets an `.active` class added to it (because of the `:class="{active: category.active}"` line in the template.

However, the DOM is not updated to show this change.

Is there anyway to update the DOM automatically when this change occurs, without using `this.$forceUpdate()` in the `changeCategory(index)` function?

edit: changed `map` to `forEach`, DOM still does not update.

edit: I am using vue-class-components with typescript

```ts
import Vue from 'app/vueExt'
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import * as Template from './services.vue'

@Component({
    mixins: [Template]
})
export default class Services extends Vue {
    categories = []

    created() {
        this.api.getServiceSetupCatagories().then((res) => {
            this.categories = res.categories
            this.categories.forEach((c, i) => {
                // adding active property to the object
                // active = true if i = 0, false otherwise
                c.active = (i)? false : true
            })
        })
    }

    changeCategory(index) {
        this.categories.forEach((c, i) => {
            c.active = (i != index)? false : true
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: `map` doesn't modify your array, it returns a new array. Therefore vue doesn't detect any change and your dom isn't updated. Try using `forEach` instead.

Comment: @EricGuan that's true, good point. I tried `forEach` and event went to the extent of using a `for` loop to change `active` property, but it had no effect. When I `console.log` the item it shows the correct `active` value, but the DOM doesn't get updated.

Comment: Seems to work for me. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/MmmZLN

Comment: @BertEvans Yeah, I am not sure what's going on. I tried your code with `map` function instead of `forEach` and that works too as intended. I am not sure why the DOM isn't updating in my case.

Comment: Technically, yes, map will work in this case too, you're just kind of mis-using it. It's intended with map that you return a new array, not just iterate the array. Does every category have an `active` property beforehand?

Comment: If the `active` property does not exist on `category` until the `changeCategory` method is called, then you are falling into a caveat in Vue and should use `Vue.set(c, "active", i != index ? false : true)`. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: @BertEvans It didn't before. But now I am adding the active property to the object before rendering (in `created()` hook). Still no effect.

Comment: As @RoyJ mentions, we need to see more code to help then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143106/discussion-between-wrahim-and-bert-evans).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussing the issue I suggested the following alternative method.

Add `activeIndex` to `data` and change the template to the following.

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="category, i in categories"
      :class="{active: activeIndex === i}"
      @click="activeIndex = i">
    <a>{{ category.service_type_name }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This appears to work for @wrahim.

I believe the underlying issue with the original code was that the `active` property was added to the `category` falling into one of Vue's [change detection caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).

Answer (score 1):

This works as expected. Your problem is not in the code you posted here. (Even using map: within map, objects are references, so modifying their members modifies the original object.)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    categories: [{
        service_type_name: 'one',
        active: false
      },
      {
        service_type_name: 'two',
        active: false
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    changeCategory(index) {
      this.categories.map((c, i) => {
        c.active = (i != index) ? false : true
      })
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.0/vue.min.js"></script>
<ul id="app">
  <li v-for="category, i in categories" :class="{active: category.active}" @click="changeCategory(i)">
    <a>{{ category.service_type_name }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```